# A problem with "Crossed Ladders Theorem"

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio

In the following diagram, $AY \parallel BZ$, $AB$ is base. $M$ is $5$ above $N$ and $N$ is $4$ above $O$. What is the height of the triangle $\Delta AOB$.
[image]
**My Work**
There is a theorem named Crossed Ladder Theorem.
In the following Diagram $\dfrac{1}{h} = \dfrac{1}{H_1} + \dfrac{1}{H_2}$
[image]
I think this problem can be transformed into this. But I don't know how to. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: I would consider drawing an x axis through your point O. Extend the parallel lines, 5 and 4. I believe you will see that classic Crossed Ladders Theorem you are looking for, just at a different scale. Your problem as written I believe is unsolvable using the crossed ladders method. See sketch . courtesy of GeoGebra. [Need to be parallel ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18h_kHthU89IBHYr1dqs75tq0oAEdzWH8/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: When you write $AY||BZ$, coded as AY||BZ, it doesn't look the same as $AY\parallel BZ,$ coded as $AY\parallel BZ,$ coded as AY\parallel BZ, since it lacks proper spacing. I edited accordingly. $$ \begin{align} & AY||BZ \\ \text{versus} & \phantom{1}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\phantom{1} \\ & AY \parallel BZ \end{align} $$

Answer (score -3):

Note that there is no statement about the angle between $AY$ and $AB$. The only constraint is that $AY$ and $BZ$ are parallel. It is therefore permissible to move $Y$ to give (amongst many others) the different arrangements shown below:

[image]

In all of these $|MC|=5$ and $|EO|=4$ and you will see that $|OF|=h$ is independent of the angle between $YA$ and $AB$.

Of particular interest is the diagram on the right, where $YA$ is perpendicular to $AB$.

This is essentially the same as your diagram for the crossed ladders:

[image]

$AM=H_2=h+4+5$

$BN=H_1=h+4$

Using the relationship you described, you now have:

$$\frac 1 h = \frac 1 {h+9} + \frac 1 {h+4}$$

Comment: But if we do so then the point $O$ will not be in the same height. I guess.

Comment: The only constraint is that the lines are parallel. I have satisfied that constraint, so it works. The angle to the perpendicular doesn't matter.

Comment: Imagine a ladder leaning against a wall. If I tell you that the top of the ladder is 3.6 m above the ground, then you know that the midpoint of the ladder is 1.8 m above the ground. You don't need to know the length of the ladder or the angle that it makes to the horizontal. It is sufficient to know the ratio. This is the same.

Comment: Don't know why I've been voted down... Any constructive comments?

Comment: I think it is not an actual solution. When we will change the angle to the perpendicular the actual intersecting point will not be in the same height. They will intersect in a different point. The question asked about the main point. In you comment, the midpoint of the ladder is 1.8m above the ground but when you'll change the angle, the height of the midpoint will be changed. So, in the question the angle is a matter.

Comment: Imagine three different ladders of different lengths leaning against a wall. If I tell you that the top of each ladder is 3.6 m above the ground, then you know that the midpoint of each ladder is 1.8 m above the ground. You don't need to know the length of the ladder or the angle that it makes to the horizontal. It is sufficient to know the ratio.

Comment: in you first diagram,  imagine $BN$ as a ladder. Its top is suppose 10 feet over the ground. but when you will change the angle, the top of the ladder will not be in the same height. $BN$ in the first and in the last diagram is not same height. so point $O$ is not in the same height.

Comment: But you are not given a restriction on the length $BN$. That's a different problem!